# Does an unmet pledge prevent a pool producing blocks, or only prevent rewards?

Tags: stake-pool, pledge

If a pool does not meet its pledge, does that prevent it from producing blocks, or only prevent rewards being paid out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The slots to make a block are pre-scheduled and the pool can make them even if the pledge is not fulfilled - but the pool will not get any rewards.

(It also means that all delegators do not get any rewards)